# При считывании из последовательного порта буфер заполняется нулями

Tags: c++, linux, serial

Программа на С++ считывает данные из последовательного порта.
А в качестве тестового устройства - Arduino, которая периодически шлет NMEA стоку в порт.

Подключение и считываение стабильно происходит без ошибок, функция `read(2)` "рапортует" об успехе и возвращает ненулевое число. Но при попытке напечатать принятое оказывается что в буфере нули.
Причем(!), периодически, первые несколько секунд все работает как положено, но затем начинают приниматься нули.

Аналогичная программа на python с библиотекой pyserial работает отлично. Т.е. проблема не в Arduino а именно в коде на С++. Я заглялнул в исходникики pyserial и выставил у себя точно такие же настройки порта как и там.

```
int m_fd = ::open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (m_fd < 0) return false;
struct termios tty;
memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));

if (tcgetattr(m_fd, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    return false;
}


ioctl(m_fd, TCIFLUSH);
cfsetspeed(&tty, B9600);
#define CMSPAR  0b10000000000  // Use "stick" (mark/space) parity
tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;  
tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD | CMSPAR);
tty.c_cflag &=~ CSTOPB;

// Enable receiver (CREAD) and ignore modem control lines (CLOCAL)
tty.c_cflag |= (CREAD | CLOCAL); 
tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL | ISIG | IEXTEN); 
tty.c_iflag &= ~INPCK;        
tty.c_iflag &= ~(INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IGNBRK);
tty.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST | ONLCR | OCRNL);    
tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;            

tcflush(m_fd, TCIFLUSH);

if (tcsetattr(m_fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
    printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    return false;
}

char buffer[4096];
pollfd fd;
fd.events = POLLIN;
fd.fd = m_fd;

while (true){
    auto result = poll(&fd, 1, 1000);

    if (!result) continue;
    if (result < 0) break;
    if(fd.revents & POLLIN){

    int n_recv = read(m_fd,buffer,4096);
    fd.revents = 0;
    printf("read from serial %d\n", n_recv);
    printf("%.*s", n_recv, buffer);

    }
    else{
    printf("error\n");
    }

}
```

В отрывке из вывода видно что сначала мы получаем валидные данные, затем получем нули, хотя количество считанных байт ненулевое и соответсвует тому объему, который действительно передается в порт. В половине случаев нули начинают приниматься сразу же при запуске программы.

```
!read from serial 32
AIVDM,1,1,,B,144fmig001Re4T4IUu6read from serial 32
h0:pp20Rn,0*40
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,144read from serial 32
bqI13002eQ0lIQhehq4tp0hA2,0*01
read from serial 1

read from serial 32
read from serial 32
read from serial 32
read from serial 32
read from serial 32
read from serial 32
read from serial 32
```

Проблема сохраняется как при неблокирующем чтении (как в листинге), так и при блокируюшем.

Comment: я вижу три варианта. 1 - так и задумано. То есть, нулевые нужно просто выбрасывать. 2 - неверные настройки порта. Хотя это странно. 3 - сломанный провод/устройство.

Comment: ОК, код компилируется, просто не проверяется `read()` на ошибки. Ну и я бы VMIN поставил в 1.

Comment: Плюс у вас всякая фигня в буфере, может ломаться терминал, очищайте буфер перед каждым вызовом `read()`.

Comment: @0andriy я вывожу результат read  (переменная n_recv) в терминал. При ошибке результат был бы отрицательным. При VMIN = 1, (т.е. при блокирующем чтении) ничего не меняется. В буфере не фигная, это AIS сообщения, они так выглядядт, там типа BASE64: кодирование бинарных данных через ASCII.

Comment: Добавили бы `\n` ко всем выводам на печать. Может у вас там `\r` сработал.